# How to set maximum distance between two finger for two finger scroll?

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad, scrolling, synaptic, mouse-gestures

I'm on a MacBook Pro running fresh Arch on Gnome 3 with xf86-input-libinput. I'm trying to find any setting to configure a maximum distance for detecting two finger for scroll, is there a way to set this?

Currently if I put one finger in the left edge of the touchpad and another finger at the right edge, and slide down the two, it still scrolls even if the fingers are totally apart. This is annoying since frequently by accident I touch the touchpad with my thumbs and a unwanted scroll event happens.

Comment: Ask developers of driver directly

Answer (score 0):

I tried to picture how you'd scroll unintentionally with your thumbs and am I right in supposing that this happens when you're typing? If that's the case, you can use `syndaemon` to disable the touchpad while you type. The utility is part of `xf86-input-synaptics` and has some sane defaults (read the man page if you're interested in tweaking them). Normally, you can just launch it as a daemon with,

```
syndaemon -d
```

If this solves your issue, you can make this permanent by adding it to your `~/.xprofile` or similar. GNOME may also have a GUI/registry setting to disable the touchpad when typing.

As for your question about browsing through available settings for your touchpad, `synclient` is your friend. Read the man page for details and run `synclient -l` to check out the current values. You can make `synclient` changes permanent by adding an xorg conf file (in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`).

Comment: I've used synclient -l already but it didn't help regarding this supposed configuration. Also, I'd really like to have the event of scrolling constrained instead of trying to fix it with palm-rejection.